Question in construct a compact set of real numbers whose limit points form a countable set
I'm reading Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis and I have a question in Exercise 2.13.
$$
K = \left\{ 0 \right\}\cup \left\{ \frac{1}{n}:n=1,2,\cdots \right\}\cup \left\{ \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}:n=m,m+1,\cdots;m=1,2,\cdots\right\}
$$
I know the limit points are $K^{\prime}=\left\{1/m:m=1,2,\cdots\right\}\cup \left\{0\right\}$.
but I want to know when $0 < x < 1$ and $x \neq 1/m$, why x is not a limit point.

Update
insighted by @fleablood
can this work?
let $m \le n, \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n+1}\le x \le \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}$
$\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\le \frac{2}{m}$，so $m \le \frac{2}{x}$, therefore there are only finite m which satisfy the inequality
let
$$
r<\min\left\{\min\left(x-\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}-x\right):\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n+1}\le x \le \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n};m\le n\right\}
$$
$N_r\left(x\right)\cap K=\emptyset$
therefore x is not a finite set

Because if $x\ne \frac 1m$ we can always find and $m$ and $k > m$ where $\frac 1m + \frac 1{k+2}< \frac 1m + \frac 1{k+1} \le x < \frac 1m + \frac 1k$ and there is an interval around $x$ that will contain no point of $K$ (other than maybe $x$ itself if $x = \frac 1m + \frac 1k$).

It kind of helps to zoom in with a mental microscope.  Look a small segment of the set between $\frac 1{m}$ to $\frac 1{m-1}$.  Under a microscope, that section of the set looks like the usual set ${\frac 1n}$.  It is $\frac 1{m-1}> \frac 1{m} +\frac 1{m+1} > \frac 1m+\frac 1{m+2} > \frac 1m + \frac 1{m+3}>....... > \frac 1m +\frac 1n > \frac 1m + \frac 1{n+1} > ...... > \frac 1m$.  By the "usual arguments" $\frac 1m$ is "infinitely" close to an infinite number $\frac 1m + \frac 1n$ but between and $\frac 1m + \frac 1{k+1}$ and $\frac 1m+\frac 1k$ there are "gaps".

Why worry about "only finite"  just take $r$ to be small enough that there aren't any.  If $x \ne \frac 1m$ then either $\frac 1m + \frac 1k < x < \frac 1m +\frac 1{k-1}$ in which case take $r < \min (x-(\frac 1m+\frac 1k),(\frac 1m +\frac 1{k-1})-x)$ and so $B_r(x)$ contains no points of $K$;  or $x = \frac 1m + \frac 1k$ in which case take $r= x-(\frac 1m + \frac 1{k+1})$.  Then $B_r(x)$ contains only $x$ itself as a point of $K$.

Just do it.
If $x \ne \frac 1m$ for any $m\in \mathbb N$, then there is an $m\in \mathbb N$ where $\frac 1m < x < \frac 1{m-1}$.
$x - \frac 1m > 0$ so there exists a $k \ge m$ where $\frac 1m + \frac 1k \le x < \frac 1m +\frac 1{k-1} \le \frac 1{m-1}$.
If $x \ne \frac 1m +\frac 1k$ we have $\frac 1m + \frac 1k < x < \frac 1m + \frac 1{k-1}$.  There are no elements of $K$ in the open intersection $(\frac 1m+\frac 1k, \frac 1m + \frac 1{k-1})$.  So $x$ is not a limit point.
If $x = \frac 1m + \frac 1k$ then $\frac 1m +\frac 1{k+1} < x=\frac 1m + \frac 1k < \frac 1m + \frac 1{k-1}$.  The only element of $K$ in the open interval $(\frac 1m +\frac 1{k+1}, \frac 1m + \frac 1{k-1})$ is $x = \frac 1m + \frac 1k$.  So there is no other element other than $x$ so $x$ is not a limit point.
That's all.
